# How do I pin MMC with a parameter to the taskbar with Chocolatey?

Tags: powershell, mmc, chocolatey

I'm using PowerShell and a Chocolatey cmdlet [`Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem`](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/blob/73baac967edb20005bde0761483c49df6911f90d/src/helpers/functions/Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem.ps1) and attempting to pin the Hyper-V Manager shortcut to the Windows taskbar. This is a 64 bit installation of Windows.

[image]

Normally you can call:

```
Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem "$env:programfiles\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

We know it's `virtmgmt.msc`. When you inspect its existing taskbar shortcut, you see that it's:

```
%windir%\system32\mmc.exe "%windir%\system32\virtmgmt.msc"
```

I've attempted to use the built-in `$env:windir`:

```
Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem '$env:WinDir\system32\mmc.exe "$env:WinDir\system32\virtmgmt.msc"'
```

This fails with:

> '$env:WinDir\system32\mmc.exe "$env:WinDir\system32\virtmgmt.msc"' does not exist, not able to pin to task bar

How can I pin an MMC shortcut like Hyper-V manager to the taskbar using `Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem`? Should I use plain old `windir%`?

[image]

Comment: I don't use that function but looked at it here, https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/blob/master/src/chocolatey.resources/helpers/functions/Install-ChocolateyPinnedTaskBarItem.ps1 maybe its related to the split path function and the fact that you are passing the mmc.exe a variable for the snapin. Kind of looks like it would not handly anything other than a simple exe path.

Comment: Yeah. I think that function may have issues handling anything other than a plain directory. Also, if you are in a 32 bit shell, c:\windows\system32\virtmgmt.msc will not be present.

Comment: For a 32-bit shell you can use c:\windows\sysnative to bypass the folder redirection.

Comment: @ferventcoder Thanks Rob; this is a 64 bit Win environment. Any thoughts on how to pin any sort of MMC to the taskbar?